# Problem with hangman project , the letters reset each time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

list_of_words = ["ability", "able", "above", "administration", "against", "agency", "along",
                "almost", "answer"]


guessword = random.choice(list_of_words)

while True:
    result = input("Enter your guess: ")

    for word in guessword:

        if word in result:
            print(word)

        else:
            print("_")
```

I'm making a hangman project. When the user enters a letter, it should be present even when the next character is inputted, but the problem is that it resets completely. How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean that the input in "result" should be available next time in the "guessword" ?

Comment: It resets each time because you don't save the result on each iteration. You need to store the result somewhere (in an array for example) and update this result at each user input.

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. Please give more details of your current output and the one you expect. Although not mandatory, meaningful names help to understand a program. For example, your `for word in guessword` is more suitable to be `for letter in guessword` as iterating over a string iterates over its characters

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your script is that you are not keeping track of the guess letters, and therefore, the letters are "reset" every iteration. Define a variable outside of the loop that keeps track of the guessed letters. In this example, `guessed_chars` is a list that is initialized with a variable amount of underscores that is determined by the length of the target word:

```
word = random.choice(list_of_words)
guessed_chars = ["_"]*len(word)
```

Now for the while loop. In this example, I use `enumerate`, which allows you to parallelly iterate over an iterable's indices and elements. Notice how we also changed the while statement to `while "".join(guessed_chars) != word`. We have to use `join` here because, remember, `guessed_chars` is a `list` and we are comparing it to a `str`. This means that it will continue to run until the joined list of correctly guessed letters equals the word.

`enumerate` is used so that we can replace the underscores in `guessed_chars` at the correct position with the correctly guess character. Then, at the end of the loop, we simply print the joined list of chars so that it appears something like: `ab___` for "above"

```
while "".join(guessed_chars) != word:
    guess_char = input("Enter your guess: ")

    for i, char in enumerate(word):
        if char == guess_char:
            guessed_chars[i] = guess_char
            
    print("".join(guessed_chars))
```

Comment: While this saves the guessed letter, it doesn't show the guessed letters that are in the word the next time it will run. I think that is what the OP wants. So if you guess `a` for `able` and guess `b` the next turn, your code will show `_b__` instead of `ab__`

Comment: @funie200 ohhhhh okay, thank you for the clarification. I will edit accordingly

Comment: @funie200 edited. Thank you again for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember the words that you have already guessed, so here I'm using a dict `players_guess` to store them

```
import random

list_of_words = ["ability", "able", "above", "administration", "against", "agency", "along",
                "almost", "answer"]


guessword = random.choice(list_of_words)
players_guess = { }

while True:
    result = input("Enter your guess: ")

    for word in guessword:

        if word in result or word in players_guess:
            players_guess[result] = True
            print(word)

        else:
            print("_")
```

Output would be like:

```
Enter your guess: a
a
_
_
_
Enter your guess: b
a
b
_
_
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing some steps:

#### Version 1

```
import random

list_of_words = ["ability", "able", "above", "administration", "against", "agency", "along", "almost", "answer"]


guessword = random.choice(list_of_words)

while True:
    result = input("Enter your guess: ")
    
    if result == guessword:
        print(guessword)
        break
    elif result == 'exit':
        break

    for i, letter in enumerate(guessword):
        if i > len(result) - 1:
            print("_", end='')
        else:
            if letter == result[i]:
                print(letter, end='')
            else:
                print("_", end='')
    
    print('\n')
```

Gives:

```
Enter your guess: ability
ab___

Enter your guess: able
ab___

Enter your guess: above
above
```

#### Version 2

As it was mentioned in comments, the rules of the game should be different, so here is the same approach yeilding a little different result

```
import random

list_of_words = ["ability", "able", "above", "administration", "against", "agency", "along", "almost", "answer"]

guessword = random.choice(list_of_words)
user_word = ['_']*len(guessword)

while True:
    user_guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
    
    if user_guess == 'exit':
        break
    elif len(user_guess) != 1:
        print('Your guess should be one letter long!')
        continue

    for i, letter in enumerate(guessword):
        if user_guess.lower() == letter:
            user_word[i] = letter
        
        print(user_word[i], end='')
            
    print('')
    if not '_' in user_word:
        print('You win!')
        break
```

Gives

```
Enter your guess: ab
Your guess should be one letter long!
Enter your guess: a
a____
Enter your guess: b
a____
Enter your guess: l
al___
Enter your guess: g
al__g
Enter your guess: o
alo_g
Enter your guess: n
along
You win!
```

#### Comments

- `while` loop allows you to be flexible: play infinitely or add some verifivation of the number of guesses (soyour choice is good).
- However, you should not forget about exit from this infinit loop (so the [break](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) keyword is very handy here);
- User can enter few letters (which could be against the rules), so we need to check it;
- User can enter UPPERCASE letter, so we need to [`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.lower#str.lower) it;
- I am using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) in this code: it helps to iterate through elements and their indices.

Comment: Am, why the '-1'? The code doing exactly what was asked: printing the letter and filling the wrong letters with "_". OP didn't ask for saving the result in the dictionary or list

Comment: Answering with just code doesn't help the OP, it just gives them the answer. It would be more helpful if you explained what your code is doing. Also, something to point out (not the reason for downvote because the original question was not clear enough): Hangman is played by guessing one letter at a time until the letters that you have correctly guessed make up the word you are trying to guess. The user is not allowed to guess more than one character at a time. This means that you do need to keep track of the guessed letters somewhere outside of the loop.

Comment: Well, it is quite straightforward, no? I think OP understands more or less how `while` and `for` loops and `print` method work. Also, I've added some comments at the end. 
About your last comment - I agree. However, I took the OP's logic: to verify each letter and print if if rightly guessed

Comment: While it may be straightforward to us, it may not be to the OP. I think it would be more clear to someone who is beginning the learning process to have some explanations on what some things are. For example, you add `enumerate` and various `break` statements which may be all new to the OP. While StackOverflow is a great place to come to for answers, it is also an extremely helpful learning tool as well. A simple explanation at the beginning of your answer that documents *what* changes you've made and *why* you've made them would be great!